# Work macro blocked in spite of valid signature

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, certificate

- I have a self-created `*.dotm` file in the `Word\STARTUP` folder.
- The visual basic project is digitally signed by my own code-signing certificate.
- The certificate is trusted (as in: appears under "Trusted Publishers" in MS Word) and is valid until next year.
- In MS Word, the setting "Disable all macros except digitally signed macros" is active.

Until recently, things worked fine, but they do not anymore - unless I switch to "Enable all macros (not recommended)", which I do not want to do permanently for apparent reasons. I am unaware of any changes made recently except updates.

What can I do? Apparently, Word does not like my signature - but it cannot be more valid than described above, can it?

**EDIT:** After some research, I stumbled over [KB3203386](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3203386/descriptionofthesecurityupdateforoffice2013june13,2017), which got installed recently.
Among the issues that it is supposed to *fix(!)* is:

> Microsoft Office files that have VBE projects that are signed by a trusted provider aren't validated correctly at open even if you have selected the Disable all macros except digitally signed macros option. This issue occurs after you install the October 2016 update (15.0.4867.1003) for Office 2013 Click-to-Run versions.

I somehow suspect that the KB rather *introduces* the problem. Then again, I'm running 15.0.4937.1000 instead of 15.0.4867.1003 anyway ...

Comment: KB3203386,does not apply to the version (build) of Office you have installed.

Comment: @Ramhound The update history begs to differ - if it were not applicable it would not have gotten installed, I suppose.

Comment: `15.0.4867.1003` was released in Oct 2016, `15.0.4937.1000` was released on June 13 2017.  So the patch was installed then `KB4023935` was installed which includes `KB3203386`

Comment: @Ramhound Ah, that makes sense: KB3203386 apparently is also from June 13, and all that might have been installed here in a single batch of updates. At any rate, I was merely surprised because KB3203386 was supposed to *cure* specifically my problem that appeared (seemingly) at the very moment it (and the rest of that bunch) got installed ... As soon as possible, I'll try to play with back-and-forth installing and uninstalling that last bunch to pinpoint the problem more exactly ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling KB3203386 of the June 13 updates really worked, immediately.

Now with some temporal distance, I can confirm once more that it caused the problem: The July updates come with [KB3213555](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3213555/descriptionofthesecurityupdateforoffice2013july11-2017), which supersedes numerous updates, including KB3203386. Consequently, when KB321555 got installed, the problem was back. Fortunately, uninstalling KB321555 helps immediately.